# Equation of tangent in parametric form to ellipse

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Given the equation of ellipse
$\frac{x^2}{9} +y^2 =1 $.

Find the tangent at P $(\frac{3}{\sqrt2},\frac{1}{\sqrt2})$.$\\$

I know how to find tangent plane but I need an answer in parametric form like the options  given ,which are
q(w) = $[\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1-w),\frac{3}{\sqrt2}(1+w)]$. Any hints?

Comment: what does q(w) mean

Comment: If you know how to find function with respect to $x$, then you can write it as parametric one: $y=f(x)$ is same $x=t, y=f(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

After you find the tangent in the form of $y=mx+c$ where $m$ and $c$ are known.

If you just want any particular parametric form, you can let $x=t$, then $y=mt+c$ and you can write it as $[t, mt+c]$.

If you are given options $[x,y]$, try to substitute the $x$ expression into $mx+c$ and verify if you get the corresponding $y$.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is:

For poin P

$$ x= 3 \cos t, y=\sin t $$

For the given point parameter $t=\pi/4$ slope

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}= \dfrac{-1}{3 \tan t}$$

Point tangent slope form

$$\dfrac{y-1/\sqrt 2}{x-3/\sqrt 2}=\dfrac13\dfrac{\sin t-1/\sqrt 2}{\cos t-1/\sqrt 2}= \dfrac{-1}{3 \tan t}$$

You have not defined what  w is. Incorporate the same into the above tangent equation.

Comment: In my opinion the standard way to get an equation of the tangent in $(x_0,y_0)$ is $$\frac{ xx_0}{9}+yy_0=1.$$

Comment: Thanks.edited it.